# Javascript nextSibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings

Trying to get next ID using nextSibling
HTML

```
<div class="flex relative" onclick="TradeThis(this.id)" id="1" style="cursor:pointer">
  <div class="relative flex-1 mr-1">
    <div class="px-3 text-xs text-center text-white border border-red-700">
      <div class="text-xxs">
        SELL • EUR
      </div>
      <div class="mb-4">
        1.10<span class="text-3xl font-bold leading-none">28</span>3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="absolute p-2 red-border-box right-0 bottom-0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function TradeThis(id) {
  if ($('id').css("display", "none")) {
    ($('id').nextSibling).show().siblings('div').showAll();
  } else if ($('id').nextSibling).css("display", "none")) {
    $('id').show().siblings('div').showAll();
  }
}
```

id is '1'
Next ID should be '2'
Something went wrong, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

### 1. Incorrect selector

`$('id')` will select an element that is `<id>`. It does not exist. If you want to use the `id` from the argument as a selector, you should construct it as such:

```
$('#' + id)
```

Alternatively, you can use string interpolation:

```
$(`#${id}`)
```

### 2. `nextSibling()` is not a jQuery method

You should be using `.next()` instead. If you really need to use the native `Node.nextSibling` property, you need to access the underlying DOM node first, i.e.

```
$('#' + id)[0].nextSibling
```

### 3. Incorrect way of checking element visibility

The use of `.css('display', 'none')` will always return the jQuery object. It simply sets the style and returns the original selection for chaining. If you want to check if an element is hidden, [use `.is(':hidden')` instead](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

---

#### Additional comment

On a side note, you shouldn't really be using inline JS to bind click events. You can give the element a class where you can bind a click event listener to, e.g.:

```
<div class="flex relative trade-this" id="1" style="cursor:pointer">
```

And then in your jQuery logic, you can do this:

```
$('.trade-this').on('click', function () {
  var $t = $(this);
  if ($t.is(':hidden')) {
    $(this).next().show().siblings('div').showAll();
  } else if ($t.next().is(':hidden')) {
    $t.show().siblings('div').showAll();
  }
});
```

Comment: @AlonEitan or `.prop('nextSibling')`

Comment: Yeah, there are several issues with the code and I'm stepping through them with updated corrections.